Java and Kotlin platform declaration clash due to same JVM signature
I am working on an app which is still using java and kotlin.
I am converting step by step but I cannot do it at once.
I have a java class:
public abstract class DefaultHomePage {
   
    abstract public CustomType getCustomType();

}

in my newly converted to kotlin file, I have :
class ProductHomePage : DefaultHomePage() {

   @Inject
   lateinit var customType: CustomType

   override fun getCustomType(): CustomType {
       return customType
   }

}

but when compiling I have an error saying that there is a Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature  and 
Any idea how to fix this ?

This has nothing to do with your Java class, the problem is var customType: CustomType.
Kotlin automatically generates getter and setter for your properties. When you declare var customType: CustomType, the compiler will also generate a getCustomType() and setCustomType() function to access this property.
The getter function clashes with the getCustomType() function that you explicitly declare, hence the error.
Just rename customType, for example:
@Inject
lateinit var localCustomType: CustomType

